# Metrics for imbalanced multi-class classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes, metric

I am looking for informations about metrics for classification with 3 unbalanced classes. I have following numbers of samples in every class:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY3KA.png)

As you can see two classes are quite balanced and one is not (and I can't add more samples to this class). I was looking for methods for imbalanced data and I know I can add class weights or use metrics like F1-score or balanced accuracy.

My questions are:

1. Which method is better?
2. Are there other good metrics for imbalanced class besides balanced accuracy, precision, recall, F1-score and ROC?
3. If I will decide to use e.g. balanced accuracy then should I make something more? Or can I use it just like accuracy for balanced classes.
4. If I will decide to make class weights can I use metrics in the same way like with balanced classes (e.g. common accuracy)?

Comment: *All* of the metrics you note are highly problematical (ROC somewhat less so). Instead, use *probabilistic* classifications and evaluate them using proper scoring rules. See the proposed duplicate.